# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence, using arrays in ODEINT

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, odeint

I am beginner in python while I know algorithm perfectly.
I need your help and I hope you help me about the following issue. I just can say, please help me. It is not important to me giving negative or positive mark for this question, just help me plz.

In following code I ran into a problem:

Let me explain: The term `m=(ss-h)` in the middle of the code with using the `datafile.txt` was at first: `m=(u[i]-h)` which I replaced `u[i]` with `ss`. Now If I want to replace `z[i]` with `aa` in order to remove for-loop and avoiding the `data_file.txt` import, what can I do?

If I just replace the `z[i]` with `aa` in this code as it is now, it gets an error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I have searched about this error and I just find that ODE takes 1-D array. As I know `aa` is 2-D array.
Now I talked about my problem. The one thing that I want is to call `m[1]` and the code automatically take `aa[1]` and `ss[1]` which it means `m[1]=(ss[1]-M-h)` and `aa[1]` is into `h` and for other `m` as well.

some helps please.
Data file is as follow:

```
0.01    32.95388698
0.012   33.87900347
0.014   33.84214074
0.016   34.11856704
0.019   34.59344598
0.023   34.93902653
0.026   35.25209633
0.031   35.74850165
0.037   36.06978761
0.043   36.43457047
```

The code is:

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import odeint

z,u=np.genfromtxt('Datafile.txt',unpack=True)

aa=np.array([0.01,0.012,0.014,0.016,0.019,0.023,0.026,0.031,0.037,0.043])
ss=np.array([32.95388698,33.87900347,33.84214074,34.11856704,34.59344598,
        34.93902653,35.25209633,35.74850165,36.06978761,36.43457047])
Cov= [[21282,-10840,1918,451,946,614,785,686,581,233],
     [0,28155,-2217,1702,74,322,380,273,424,487],
     [0,0,6162,-1593,1463,419,715,580,664,465],
     [0,0,0,5235,-722,776,588,591,583,403],
     [0,0,0,0,7303,-508,1026,514,596,315],
     [0,0,0,0,0,3150,-249,800,431,358],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,3729,-88,730,321],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3222,-143,568],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3225,-508],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5646]]

def ant(z,O_m,O_D):           
   return 1/sqrt(((1+z)**2)*(1+O_m*z)-z*(2+z)*O_D)

def HDE(y,z):
    a=1/(1+z)
    p=log(alpha+beta*a)
    pd=beta*a/(alpha+beta*a)    
    dydz = -((C**2-y)*((pd/p)*(y-2)-(pd**3)/(p**2)+(pd**2)/p+1.5*(y*(b+1)-1))/(1-(pd**2)/(p**2)+2*pd/p-0.5*(C**2+y)))*(1/(1+z))
    return dydz

b=0.01
M=4
C=0.5
O_m=0.23
alpha=1
beta=2

for i in range (len(z)):   
    y0=1-O_m
    z0=0

    z1=z[i]

    y = odeint(HDE,y0,[z0,z1])                       
    O_D=y[-1,0]
    q=quad(ant,0,z[i],args=(O_m,O_D))[0]     
    h=5*log10((1+z[i])*(299000/70)*q)+25     # Here is the main problem of my code
                                             # h and q must work with aa instead of z[i]  

    fl=(ss-h)


    l1=[[fl[0],fl[1],fl[2],fl[3],fl[4],fl[5],fl[6],fl[7],fl[8],fl[9]]]
    l2=[[fl[0]],[fl[1]],[fl[2]],[fl[3]],[fl[4]],[fl[5]],[fl[6]],[fl[7]],[fl[8]],[fl[9]]]

    mm=np.dot(l2,Cov)
    zz=np.dot(mm,l2)
    hh=np.linalg.det(zz)   #calculation of determinant

print (hh)
```

I appreciate your help and your attention

Comment: My guess is that `quad` function won't accept an array as an input. You can circumvent this by putting your code into a function f(x) and using `numpy.vectorize` , but in the end it implements a for loop inside anyway. Alternatively, you can just run a list comprehension e.g. `out=[f(x) for x in range(len(z))]`, avoiding the explicit `for` loop call again.

Comment: Hi bob and Ethan, could you add some desired output? I mean, you give some input, and what the function returns? Also, do you have an example of Cov= # a 10*10 matrix ? how that matrix looks like?

Comment: @DamianLattenero Updated My friend.

Comment: Please make a minimal and reproducible example. You can make your data very small and write it or generate it randomly or add a link to the file. It would be much easier to help if we could run your code.

Comment: @Bob great, now, when you do `print (hh)` what wish you to be the output'

Comment: @yevgeniy Thank you my friend, I think you are very close to solve my problem. I understood what you said but if it is solve my problem, sorry to say that, I do not know how to use it in my whole code.

Comment: @DamianLattenero well it is just a number for example `hh=32.34252325`. I took  some parameters such as `alpha`, `beta`, `M` and... as a constant parameter. If we use loop for each of them we can have more than 1 answer for `hh`. But the normal answer for `hh` is something around `32` plus minus 50 or something like that.

Comment: @DavidDale I just updated the code. And `z` and `u` in data file are `aa` and `ss` in my code.

Comment: @bob I still cannot run your code: HDE and ant are not defined. Please remove all the unnecessary details.

Comment: @DavidDale I added right now all needed data and corrected typos. There is just error in out put related to my problem. Code is quiet correct.

Comment: @DamianLattenero if you reach the correct code and the answer is huge, it is needed to multiply it in 10^-6.

Comment: @Bob, sorry for quibbling, but the code still does not work. l2 is 5*1, and Cov is 10*10, so they cannot multiply.

Comment: @DavidDale No problem, Updated. Just forgot to add 5 more arrays

Comment: could you add a link to the datafile? to run some tests?

Comment: @DamianLattenero data file has exactly 2 column, `aa` and `ss`. but I just wrote it. Updated code.

Answer (score 0):

For component of matrix you can use the following construction:
It is clear and does not need any explanation.

the second paragraph choose each component separately and use it in matrixproperly.

```
  def new_calculation(n):    
    yn = odeint(HDE,y0,[z0,xx[n]])  
    yyn=yn[-1,0]
    O_Dn=1-O_m-(1/(2*rc*yyn))
    q=quad(ant,0,xx[n],args=(O_m,O_Dn))[0]     
    h=log10((1+xx[n])*(299000/70)*q)+25     
    fn=(ss[n]-h)
    return fn


f_list = []
    for i in range(2):  # the value '2' reflects matrix size
        f_list.append(new_calculation(i))

    rdag=[f_list]
    rmat=[[f] for f in f_list]

    mm=np.dot(rdag,Cov)
    zz=np.dot(mm,rmat)
    hh=np.linalg.det(zz)
```